# Data Binding Multiple Inputs for One LiveData

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm writing an app for creating trivia questions. Creating a set of trivia questions is done through a simple form with one EditText for the title, then a list of pairs of EditText for each question with its prompt and answer. I understand how to do 2-way data binding for a single EditText, but I'm not sure how to do it in this situation where I want to implement 2-way binding for the prompt and answer EditText of each question.

Each Question has a prompt and an answer:

```
data class Question(
  val prompt: String,
  val answer: String
)
```

Each Trivia has a title and a set of Questions:

```
data class Trivia(
  val title: String, 
  val questions: List<Question>
)
```

My Android ViewModel fetches a persisted Trivia and exposes it as LiveData for data binding:

```
class EditTriviaViewModel : ViewModel() {
  val title = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val questions = MutableLiveData<List<Question>>() // or List<MutableLiveData<Question>>?
  ...
}
```

I know how to bind the title input:

```
<EditText
  android:text="@={viewModel.title}"
  ... />
```

But I do not know how to bind the inputs for each question so that the ViewModel is updated as I type the prompt or answer for each question. So far, all I have is a question layout file containing two vertically stacked EditText.